# How to increase zoom in for persp3d plot?

Tags: r

I created the following plot through persp3D (see attached picture).

```
require(plot3D)
persp3D(z = sample_mean, theta = 120)
```

However, the plot appears to be pretty small. Moreover, I wasn't able to find any command that zoomes in.
Is there any way that the plot covers the whole plot window in R?

Many thanks in advance !!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the margins of the plotting area:

```r
library(plot3D)

set.seed(1)
sample_mean = matrix(rnorm(81), 9)
persp3D(z = sample_mean, theta = 120, zlim = c(-10, 10))
```

[image]

```r
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 2))
persp3D(z = sample_mean, theta = 120, zlim = c(-10, 10))
```

[image]

Also, try dragging your plotting area to make it larger, which may reduce the relative sizes of the margins.

<sup>Created on 2022-11-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>